# installing CuPy with Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, cupy

I want to pass tensors from Pytorch to CuPy and back to do some ops not available in Pytorch. What's the recommended way to install them together?

I already installed Pytorch using conda, and it has installed cudatoolkit package. I'd prefer to use conda to install cupy as well. However CuPy installation instructions [recommend uninstalling cudatoolkit](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#cupy-always-raises-cupy-cuda-compiler-compileexception) (at the very bottom).

So, how do I make sure both Pytorch and CuPy are using the same cuda version, as well as CuDNN, NVCC, etc? Or should I not use conda to install cupy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `conda install -c conda-forge cupy` and it should work. That part of documentation is outdated and [to be updated](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/3052).

Comment: Just to clarify: will conda-installed CuPy use system-wide CUDA installation, or the conda-installed cudatoolkit (installed by the conda-installed Pytorch)? Also, I see the note about nvcc, so do I need to run `conda install nvcc` and `conda install cudnn` after CuPy is installed?

Comment: oh hi Michael, didn't see your comment until now. I suppose [I answered your questions](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/3052#issuecomment-595011104)?